# Why do military only use consumable portal scrolls to rather than reusable ones?

Tags: magic, military, travel, portal

There are 2 kinds of portal scrolls which are equally reliable and can handle similar traffic regardless of distance, the consumable or one time use only and the reusable or can be used more than 2 times very handy and economic. So once the consumable portal is closed all of it's history is erased along with the scroll, as for the reusable the history will be rewritten or overlap instead! Normally both types of portal scrolls have their pros and cons but I wonder why the military would ban the use of reusable scroll only?

Comment: Your question contains the answer, I think. Why would *the military* want to have resources the enemy can capture and use against them?

Comment: How reliable are the scrolls in general? Is there a small chance of owning a defective one? Perhaps both types are guaranteed to work on the first use, but on successive attempts, the reusable scrolls degrade in quality and may have unintended consequences.

Comment: The answer to almost any such questions is "Ask the devs at Blizzard Entertainment".

Comment: "So once the consumable portal is closed all of it's history is erased along with the scroll, as for the reusable the history will be rewritten or overlap instead!  . ." what does "history " mean here? Does it mean the scroll contains a record of every time it was used?

Comment: Do they ban it for everyone, like the export of certain chips today? Can a reusable scroll be discarded in the same way a one-time scroll can?

Comment: "reusable the history will be rewritten or overlap instead" Where do these portals **go**?  What history are you talking about?  Are these time travel ports, world hopping portals, portal video game blue/red portals -- what are you talking about?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As a military one of the least things you want is that the weapons you carry will be reused by the enemy you are attacking. That's why very often weapons and supplies are destroyed before surrendering or defeat.

Now it's easy to imagine that letting an enemy have easy access to a portal with which they can easily go around your defenses is definitely a no no for any military planner. Plus there is also the need to ensure that the supplied ones are used for what they are meant, and not for less martial purposes, like visiting the brothel in the nearby city and getting back unnoticed while supposedly being on guard duty.

So, single use portal scrolls and a very severe release policy will ensure that no misuse is done.

Answer (score 7):

Security and secrecy are great answers... but I thought also of pilots being bolted into kamikaze aircraft and manned torpedos in WWII... to help them remember their honor.

To a much less permanent degree, when I was enlisted I experienced hundreds of little military rules about where you are and what you are doing... all of them designed to prevent you from straying off a very specific path.

It would be nice if our fighting boys didn't hop to the theater of war, then immediately bounce to Aruba, then back after the fighting was over to be there when the generals show up.

Comment: *Be where you're supposed to be when you're supposed to be there.* +1

Answer (score 6):

### Secrecy and security:

Armies could have a number of motives for this. The biggest I can think of is secrecy.

- **Secrecy:**  A huge part of military activity is making sure the enemy doesn't know what you have done, are doing, and plan to do. If a scroll is on the battlefield, some of them will be captured. So if you have a supply depot full of valuables, your enemy can use the reusable scroll to locate and send troops to attack it. You can find out where and when these troops have deployed and re-deployed. If you figure out the enemy commander teleports to the same location once a week (and it's corroborated that other commanders do so as well) then you've just located where and when they have their planning sessions and kill all their senior leadership in one fell swoop. With a one-shot scroll, no problem. Your mage using the scroll still has to know when and where the secret meetings are held, but a suicide pill or a memory-wipe spell can take care of that. A reusable scroll is physical proof, and a captured mage could be lying to you, or mis-remembering, or a plant to feed you false info.
- **Independence and trust**: Military organizations also often believe that their units and commanders should be capable of functioning independently. Perhaps your army wants officers to make due with what they have as much as possible. This approach could vary from army to army. An army with a strong central command that doesn't trust their officers to be competent or trustworthy (think the Red army in WW2) would want commanders to be dependent on the central supply, only getting a new scroll every time they use one, so they don't get independent ideas and go off on their own/rebel. An army that encourages maximum independence would want the concern over wasting single-use items to restrict the desire to be a weak commander and be constantly checking in/topping off (possibly limited) supplies.
- **Cost**: Perhaps the one-use scrolls are cheap. The supply chain folks want units to be able to resupply magically, but reusable scrolls are expensive. Rather than train your troops so they are used to easy supply refills, you give them dirt-cheap scrolls and let them know they can get another one when they use the last one. When you're fighting, the eventual cost of using disposable scrolls adds up, but in peace time, you don't have to invest in expensive reusable equipment that you don't use until a war breaks out.

Answer (score 5):

**Reusable scrolls are more expensive:**
There's no good way to modify one after creating it. A normal person might get a reusable scroll pair to go between their home and work, and get a new scroll when they change jobs or houses.

The military doesn't have a "commute". Scrolls are for emergency evacuation in battle, or moving troops around in mass. There's very little back-and-forth movement, and even if a reusable scroll isn't that much more expensive, there's very little point in creating one for a one-time move. They may have a few reusable scrolls around for moving between common destinations, but they're still going to be ordering single-use scrolls by the truckload.

**Reusable scrolls have a shorter range:**
Teleportation cost increases with distance. While it's possible to create a reusable scroll that can teleport you to the next city, it's really expensive, and past that it gets even worse. Single-use scrolls, on the other hand, don't bother to absorb the magical backlash without damage. That gives them much better range, at the cost of literally disintegrating upon use.

**Reusable scrolls need skill and time to use:** A single-use scroll is simple; just break the seal, and the spell inside will auto-cast. A reusable scroll requires someone to read it, make the appropriate actions, and focus properly. It's not that difficult, and most people can learn how, but doing so while being shot at is an issue. Using a reusable scroll after being shot is even worse.

Answer (score 4):

Efficient armed forces run their logistics and acquisitions basing themselves on cost-benefit analysis. If they have a preference for the one time usage scroll, it's because it is cheaper to mass produce and/or distribute to troops, or for security reasons as mentioned in [Dutch's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/200156/21222).

The multiuse scroll might be called "economic" but it might be the kind of economy that only the filthy rich can use. Also even if they are indeed economic, if a squad is not supposed to be teleporting much during battles than the cheaper, one use one would be preferred.

Comment: I assumed this was why all the peons had muzzle loading muskets and all the named characters had lever action rifles or revolvers in the Last Samurai movie.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the mechanics of teleportation there can be several reasons for this:

1. reusable scrolls require user input of coordinates

If your reusable scrolls require user input, all military personnel has to go through special teleportation training: Memorise coordinates; learn to calculate coordinates; learn to input them; etc. This can be costly, time-consuming, and dangerous since your enemies can find out the coordinates of your bases by interrogating your soldiers.

Single-use scrolls with fixed coordinates do not require any training apart from scroll activation. They can be used easily by any level of military personnel. As an added bonus, soldiers cannot use these scrolls for unregulated unsupervised activities.

2. reusable scrolls require special resources to activate

Teleportation cannot be cheap, otherwise, there is no need for the military -- a group of elite assassins will suffice. Single-use scrolls can be already imbued with the power necessary for teleportation and do not need any special resources to activate. Reusable scrolls need to be recharged/require a mage/whatever, therefore their use is limited to people and situations where necessary resources are at hand. It may be possible to have 'charged' reusable scrolls, but it can be potentially dangerous due to the human factor -- someone forgot to charge scrolls and the entire division is wiped out. Single-use scrolls are much more reliable in this sense.

3. single-use scrolls create less stable portals (or whatever your magic system calls for) and make it harder for enemies to trace movements

Single-use scrolls create fewer (or more, it does not matter as long as the final result is the same) spatial disturbances as reusable scrolls, so it is harder to trace movements. If your enemy cannot trace your movements your chances of successful ambush or escape are much higher. It also makes it easier to hide HQ and resupply bases.

4. reusable scrolls can teleport only to a specific set of coordinates

Again, it depends on the mechanics of teleportation. You can make your reusable scrolls as 'keys' opening already existing spatial corridors that lead to specific destinations. It is surely handy for trade and civilian transportation (easier to control, regulate, and tax), but it is impractical for the military. Your single-use scrolls will be 'true' teleportation scrolls that create independent spatial corridors.

---

These are just some examples of what can be done. You can come up with something more suitable for your particular setting if you look carefully at teleportation mechanics, scroll production, and methods of warfare.

Answer (score 3):

**Stop the Enemy using our Portals.**

Suppose we want to port from the front lines to the garrison and close the portal after us. To close the portal we simply activate the scroll a second time. The catch is that the scroll cannot be put through its own portal without catastrophic consequences (potential plot point).

That means someone must stay on the front lines to close the portal. This is a problem in a *total retreat* scenario where we want everyone back to the garrison as soon as possible. It means we have to either (a) leave someone behind or (b) leave the portal open. This means our enemy could use the portal to invade our garrison from inside. Especially bad if the garrison location is secret.

**Other Ideas:**

**Benefits/Drawbacks:**
Perhaps reusable scrolls are created with the anchor points already written into the spell; but single use scrolls have the anchor points decided just before casting. It's a marvel of runic technology that the spell can be *suspended* like this, and altogether too much to hope for a reusable version of the same.

**Catastrophic consequences:** The commanders of garrisons A and B refuse to hold reusable scrolls to travel between the two garrisons. The worry is that the enemy could sneak in, steal the scrolls and, by passing them through their own portals explode both garrisons at once. Kablammo!

**Damage control:** A lost or captured reusable scroll is much worse than a lost/captured single-use scroll. I presume you are thinking about a story where the protagonists need to teleport some number of times, and then stop teleporting at risk of trivializing the plot. Well guess what, preventing this kind of hero shananigans is exactly the reason their enemies (and everyone else) only use single-use scrolls in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

A **tradition of boat- and bridge-burning.**

There are [a variety of ancient accounts](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/which-military-commanders-burned-their-own-ships) (and even a [quote from the art of war](http://changingminds.org/disciplines/warfare/art_war/sun_tzu_11-8.htm)) of military commanders burning their own boats, or the bridges behind them.

The (rather Machiavellian) idea is your troops will fight harder when they know retreat isn't an option; and the proof of your determination will inspire fear in your enemies.

Perhaps this was done in your society's most famous battles, and is maintained to this day *partly* for functional reasons but *also* for tradition - just like armies maintain swords and silly hats.